# Remove space between two '</p>'

Tags: php, str-replace

I'm trying to replace double generated `</p>` with:

```
$excerpt = str_replace('</p></p>', '</p>', $excerpt);
```

But my PHP generates a lot of spaces between first `</p>` and second `</p>`

How to remove all spaces between the `</p>` tags?

My string looks like that:

```
<blockquote>
  <p>Text</p> <!-- here's unknown amount of space generated by php --> </p>
</blockquote>
```

This is related to [this](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/158430/excerpt-filter-is-adding-p-in-incorrect-place) question on WordPress Stackexchange.

Comment: Use [preg_replace()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) instead

Comment: You could also use the text editor instead of the Visual Editor when working with Wordpress Content, then enter just pure HTML code.

Comment: extra space introduced as a result of blockquote

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`preg_replace()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php) you can make this substitution using the following regular expression:

```
/<\/p>\s+<\/p>/
```

Your code would look something like this:

```
$pat = '/<\/p>\s+<\/p>/';
$replacement = '<\p>';
$excerpt = preg_replace( $pat, $replacement, $excerpt );
```

Lets break this regular expression:

1. `<\/p>` - matches a closing `<\p>` element (note the escaping of the slash)
2. `\s+` - matches one or more whitespace characters
3. `<\/p>` - matches a closing `<\p>` element (note the escaping of the slash)

Usually you would need an add a global modifier `g` to the regular expression so that the substitution will occur for every occurrence of the matched pattern but the `preg_replace` function will perform global replacements by default.

Here is an example that you can test and play with - http://regex101.com/r/dA3kU0/2

Comment: This: `/<\/p>\s+<\/p>/` works, but this: `/<\/p>\s+<\/p>/g` throws an error: `Warning: preg_replace(): Unknown modifier 'g' in ...`

Comment: @RafcioKowalsky - Apparently you don't need that `g` modifier because the function will perform global replacements by default. - I've updated my answer to reflect that.